# Program for number game

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, logic

I tried writing a C++ program for [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/8286/10-friends-play-a-number-game/8297). I am assuming all players play perfectly and the program is also playing perfectly to counter it. I tried using recursion (by reducing the problem into 2 smaller ones at each step). The value given with 'final state' tells you whether you will win (1) or lose (0). What is wrong with my code, since manually working out the solutions gives different results.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

bool win(int player,int no_of_players,int counter)
{
    if(no_of_players==1)
        return 1;
    if(counter>=10)
    {
        --no_of_players;
        counter=0;
    }
    if(player>no_of_players)
        player=0;
    if(win(player+1,no_of_players,counter+1)==0)
    {
        cout<<"\nMove 1";
        return 1;
    }
    if(win(player+1,no_of_players,counter+2)==0)
    {
        cout<<"\nMove 2";
        return 1;
    }
    cout<<"\nLosing position";
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int a=win(0,2,1);
    cout<<"\nFinal state :"<<a;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: at what point in the code do you first notice something wrong?

Comment: When you used the debugger, and executed each statement one at a time, which line causes the issue?

Comment: @TankorSmash I was just trying the program with simple situations such as win(1,2,1) and win(2,2,1). I got 0 as the final answer in both situations, making it seem as though neither player wins in a 2 player game.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I don't know to use a debugger. The error is logical, not in the syntax. Can a debugger help?

Comment: A debugger can usually let you see what variables have what values for the given line you are at (which, btw, you can step through line by line at your own pace while the program is 'paused' by the debugger).

Comment: Spend some time, learn to use the debugger.  A lot faster than having folks at StackOverflow perform a code review or inspection.

Comment: Sorry, but I couldn't understand anything about the debugger.

Comment: Learning to use a debugger is one of the most important skills to have as a programmer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as Jeffrey pointed out, this game cannot be solved for more that two players. So my understanding that the question now is why your program doesn't work for two players.

The biggest issue in your logic for the two player game is that you misinterpret the value of `counter`. What `counter` effectively means in your code is what value the player needs to write right now (also having an option to write `counter + 1` after that as well). So you properly assume that if `counter >= 10`, then a player loses, though the way you handle it might not be correct. What I would do, since we are talking about a two player game here, is just `return 0` immediately if `counter` is greater or equal to `10`.

Now to the main issue -- the way you call the recursive function. The first time you call it is correct

```
if(win(player+1,no_of_players,counter+1)==0)
```

You pass it to another player (by the way, you are not using the `player` variable in any way, so I would just remove it from the code altogether), writing `counter` on the board, and by this time we know that `counter` is not `10`, so it is safe to write it.

Your second call, however, is wrong.

```
if(win(player+1,no_of_players,counter+2)==0)
```

Here you effectively passing a turn to the next player, after writing both `counter` and `counter + 1` on the board. But wait, what if `counter + 1` is `10`? You need to call it like this:

```
if(counter + 1 < 10 && win(player+1,no_of_players,counter+2)==0)
```

In other words, do not even consider taking two turns if the second turn would result in printing 10.

Finally, the last issue in your thinking is that your program will return a different value if you call it as `win(1, 2, 1)` and `win(2, 2, 1)`. You are not using the variable `player`, so it cannot return different values. Your `win` function doesn't say whether player with ordinal `player` wins or not, what it says is whether **current** player wins or not. So to test that it actually works, it makes more sense to change the initial value `counter`, simulating different turns by the first player, to see how the return value changes. For instance, the first player loses, so `win(1, 2, 1)` is `0`, and no matter what turn the first player makes, the second player wins, so `win(2, 2, 2)` and `win(2, 2, 3)` are `1`.

Here's how it could look. I did just two changes to your code: made it `return 0` immediately if the `counter` is `10` and changed the way the second recursive call is made as described above. I did not remove `player` and `no_of_players` variables, but they are not really used in the code anymore:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

bool win(int player,int no_of_players,int counter)
{
    if(no_of_players==1)
        return 1;
    if(counter>=10)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if(player>no_of_players)
        player=0;
    if(win(player+1,no_of_players,counter+1)==0)
    {
        cout<<"\nMove 1";
        return 1;
    }
    if(counter + 1 < 10 && win(player+1,no_of_players,counter+2)==0)
    {
        cout<<"\nMove 2";
        return 1;
    }
    cout<<"\nLosing position";
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int a=win(0,2,1);
    cout<<"\nFinal state :"<<a<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a bunch of issues with your approach.

The main one is that since this is not a simple two-player min-max, you cannot simply return one score, recursively. You have to return the score each player would get, for each play of a given player. Something like:

void  scores(int currentPlayer, int toWrite, int outScores[], int nbOut)

Would return the score of all players in *outScores*, if *currentPlayer* were to write one or two number, from *toWrite*, with *nbOut* players already out.

Still, this is not optimal. Recursively trying all solutions for 10 players means going more than 50 levels down, with a branching factor of 2. You need some dynamic programming to make it efficient.

I did code it. It works very well for 4 players, with a max value of 10. It gets really slow for higher number of players. As I said, dynamic programming is what you are looking for, here.

Also, I assume a player would prefer playing just once if it would still get to lose in the same order.

```cpp
#include <memory.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int NB_PLAYERS = 3;
const int MAX_VALUE = 10;

vector<pair<int, int>> scores(int currentPlayer, int toWrite, int outScores[], int nbOut)
{
    if (outScores[currentPlayer] == -1) // we're already out, lets just have the next player play
    {
        return scores((currentPlayer + 1) % NB_PLAYERS, toWrite, outScores, nbOut);
    }

    if (toWrite == MAX_VALUE) // one player is out
    {
        vector<pair<int, int>> ret;
        if (nbOut + 2 != NB_PLAYERS)
        {
            outScores[currentPlayer] = -1; // so the game can continue without us
            ret = scores((currentPlayer + 1) % NB_PLAYERS, 1, outScores, nbOut + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i=0; i < NB_PLAYERS; i++)
            {
                if (outScores[i] == 0)
                {
                    outScores[i] = NB_PLAYERS; // set the winner
                }
            }
        }
        outScores[currentPlayer] = nbOut + 1;
        ret.push_back(pair<int, int>(1,currentPlayer));
        return ret;
    }

    if (toWrite + 1 == MAX_VALUE) // no point playing to lose, if we can avoid it
    {
        vector<pair<int, int>> ret;
        ret = scores((currentPlayer + 1) % NB_PLAYERS, toWrite + 1, outScores, nbOut);
        ret.push_back(pair<int,int>(1,currentPlayer));
        return ret;
    }

    int scoresIfPlay1[NB_PLAYERS];
    int scoresIfPlay2[NB_PLAYERS];
    vector<pair<int,int>> ret1;
    vector<pair<int,int>> ret2;

    memcpy(scoresIfPlay1, outScores, sizeof(int) * NB_PLAYERS);
    memcpy(scoresIfPlay2, outScores, sizeof(int) * NB_PLAYERS);

    ret1 = scores((currentPlayer + 1) % NB_PLAYERS, toWrite + 1, scoresIfPlay1, nbOut); //recurse with both choices
    ret2 = scores((currentPlayer + 1) % NB_PLAYERS, toWrite + 2, scoresIfPlay2, nbOut);

    if (scoresIfPlay2[currentPlayer] > scoresIfPlay1[currentPlayer]) // pick the solution that yields the higher score
    {
        memcpy(outScores, scoresIfPlay2, sizeof(int) * NB_PLAYERS);
        ret2.push_back(pair<int,int>(2,currentPlayer));
        return ret2;
    }
    else
    {
        memcpy(outScores, scoresIfPlay1, sizeof(int) * NB_PLAYERS);
        ret1.push_back(pair<int,int>(1,currentPlayer));
        return ret1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int outScores[NB_PLAYERS] = {0};

    vector<pair<int, int>> plays = scores(0, 1, outScores, 0);

    for(int i = 0; i < NB_PLAYERS; i++)
    {
        cout << "Player " << i << " has score " << outScores[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Plays were: " << endl;
    for(int i = plays.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        cout << "player " << plays[i].second << " plays " << plays[i].first << " times." << endl;
    }

}
```

**=== old answer ===**

The problem, as stated, doesn't allow you to tell whether you will win or lose. In order to do so, you must change the rules in one way or another: Since there would be 9 losers and 1 winner, any of the non-winning players can change the way they play and while they still lose, affect who wins. E.g. player x loses either way but can make it a win or a loss for player y. How x will play is not defined.

You need to pick a scenario:

- Every player will try to eliminate every other player as fast as possible, as long as it doesn't make them lose.
- Or, being eliminated later yields more points. Players will maximise their score.

In any case, the solution should be more complex than above. You probably want to recurse over

*int scoreFromPosition(int player,int no_of_players,int counter)*

which would return the max score player *player* can get when *no_of_player* players are left, with counter currently being *counter*.

Comment: I am assuming that all players play perfectly. isn't that enough to determine whether you can possibly win, for a given scenario?

Comment: Definitely not, in some cases. Consider a simple 3-player game where A can not win. He can play x or y, but will lose either way. If A plays x, B will have a winning move. If A plays y, C will have a winning move. So, A's play is undefined. Now imagine a further game, with 4 player, leading to a situation as above. D will be unable to predict A's behaviour, even trough "perfect-play" assumptions.

Comment: Okay, but my algorithm doesn't work even for a 2 player game. I know for a fact that the person playing second can always win. Could you please find the error. I can put a bounty (50) since I anyway don't use the site (SO) much.

Comment: Programmed a recursive, but inefficient C++ solution. Is it worth some bounty ? :-)